# How to access internal activity logs from Xbox One S

Tags: xbox-one

We need to pull usage logs from an XBox One S (offline): start-up & shutdown timestamps (like you'd get from EventLog in Windows, for example).

The Microsoft Family Parental Controls are not enabled, so we need to pull whatever internal/offline logs are available.
Does anyone know how this can be done?